# Get last three records for every loop in a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe like the following:

```
    User           Warehouse    R_Number    Date    Missing
0   Delhi_Goa    Goa Warehouse  5046    2022-05-24  TRRFF.1T22AD0041
1   Delhi_Goa    Goa Warehouse  5046    2022-05-24  PPRFP.1T22AD0017
2   Delhi_Goa    Goa Warehouse  5048    2022-05-24  TRRFF.1T22AD0031
3   Delhi_Goa    Goa Warehouse  5048    2022-05-24  TRRFF.1T22AD0037
4   Delhi_Goa    Goa Warehouse  5048    2022-05-24  PPRFP.1T22AD0039
5   Delhi_Goa    Goa Warehouse  5048    2022-05-24  TRRFF.1T22AD0026
```

I want to loop over the DataFrame and perform actions for every row where the result will be dependent on last three records

for eg.

```
Loop 1 to fetch index 0 
loop 2 to fetch index 0,1
loop 3 to fetch index 0,1,2
loop 4 to fetch index 1,2,3
loop 5 to fetch index 2,3,4
loop 6 to fetch index 3,4,5
```

How can I do loop the dataframe for last three records ?

Comment: Using loops is rarely the best method when it comes to pandas. What is it that you're trying to achieve, what is your desired output?

Comment: @BeRT2me I am going to do a few calculations based on the retrieved df and unable to do them without using the loop

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.rolling`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.rolling.html):

```
for g in df.rolling(3):
    print (g)

   User                Warehouse  R_Number        Date           Missing
0     0  Delhi_Goa Goa Warehouse      5046  2022-05-24  TRRFF.1T22AD0041
   User                Warehouse  R_Number        Date           Missing
0     0  Delhi_Goa Goa Warehouse      5046  2022-05-24  TRRFF.1T22AD0041
1     1  Delhi_Goa Goa Warehouse      5046  2022-05-24  PPRFP.1T22AD0017
   User                Warehouse  R_Number        Date           Missing
0     0  Delhi_Goa Goa Warehouse      5046  2022-05-24  TRRFF.1T22AD0041
1     1  Delhi_Goa Goa Warehouse      5046  2022-05-24  PPRFP.1T22AD0017
2     2  Delhi_Goa Goa Warehouse      5048  2022-05-24  TRRFF.1T22AD0031
   User                Warehouse  R_Number        Date           Missing
1     1  Delhi_Goa Goa Warehouse      5046  2022-05-24  PPRFP.1T22AD0017
2     2  Delhi_Goa Goa Warehouse      5048  2022-05-24  TRRFF.1T22AD0031
3     3  Delhi_Goa Goa Warehouse      5048  2022-05-24  TRRFF.1T22AD0037
   User                Warehouse  R_Number        Date           Missing
2     2  Delhi_Goa Goa Warehouse      5048  2022-05-24  TRRFF.1T22AD0031
3     3  Delhi_Goa Goa Warehouse      5048  2022-05-24  TRRFF.1T22AD0037
4     4  Delhi_Goa Goa Warehouse      5048  2022-05-24  PPRFP.1T22AD0039
   User                Warehouse  R_Number        Date           Missing
3     3  Delhi_Goa Goa Warehouse      5048  2022-05-24  TRRFF.1T22AD0037
4     4  Delhi_Goa Goa Warehouse      5048  2022-05-24  PPRFP.1T22AD0039
5     5  Delhi_Goa Goa Warehouse      5048  2022-05-24  TRRFF.1T22AD0026
```